# drupal_get_form page callback usage

Tags: drupal

```
function example_menu() {
  $items['admin/config/example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example',
    'description' => 'example configuration',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('example_admin_settings'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer example'),
    'file' => 'example.admin.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'example'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

In the above code I am confused how it works. The page callback is drupal_get_form and the page arguments is example_admin_settings. My question is how exactly does this work?

I know that drupal_get_form probably ends up calling example_admin_settings which return system_settings_form. Could someone point me to the right docs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right path.

When you access `admin/config/example`, **[`drupal_get_form`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/6)**`('example_admin_settings')` is executed. `example_admin_settings()` itself will return an array which has its contents based on the **[form api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6)**, something like:

```
$form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'input',
    '#title' => 'Insert your name here: ',
);
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
);

return $form;
```

Drupal will render and output the form automatically for you.
Also, consider posting your next questions about Drupal at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

this is example is like making something like this

```
function example_menu() {
  $items['admin/config/example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example',
    'description' => 'example configuration',
    'page callback' => '_my_page_content_function',
    'access arguments' => array('administer example'),
    'file' => 'example.admin.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'example'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function _my_page_content_function(){
 return drupal_get_form('example_admin_settings') ; 
} 

function example_admin_settings($form, $form_state) {
  ... return my form 
}
```

in your example you asking drupal to create page and the content of this page is the content that returned by the function `drupal_get_form` when we pass the argument `example_admin_settings` to it.

**SUMMARY:**

`page callback` is the name of the function that return the content of our page when we pass the  argument `page aruguments` to

sorry for my english
mmmm need more details ?